# Exporting two layers' data as geospatially dependent tables (preferably to XML) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, esri-geodatabase, xml, geodatabase-xml

I am pretty new to in-depth GIS Work, so I may be using the wrong terminology.

If I have a map in QGIS where I have two layers, can I export their tables, with the bottom layer info being sorted dependent on the top layer by geography?

So, for example, if I have a map of public mail drop boxes across the state, marked 1-500, then a layer underneath that of counties in the state, is there any way I can export the Data of the Top layer (Box Number, Address, etc.) with the data of the bottom layer (county name) following it, correctly sorted by their geography? So the final table would read "Box 492/Brighton Post Office/Yorkshire County"?

I know there is a Database export to XML in QGIS, but it seems to only let me export one layer, and then I would have to go back and edit that data manually anyway since it wouldn't be reading the geospatial relationship of the two layers.

Comment: If you also wish to ask about doing this in ArcGIS Online then that can be done in a separate question. However, for this question I think you’ll have more luck with QGIS.

Comment: QGIS has a tool called `Join attributes by location`. If you choose your mail box layer as the `Base Layer` and the county layer as the `Join Layer` it will create a new point layer from the mail boxes with the attributes of the counties they intersect added.

There are various spatial predicates you can choose from. `intersect` or `within` will be the most appropriate. Be aware that `within` will not make a join if the point is exactly on the boundary of a polygon, however.